# Convert from C# to C++/cli - For Vertical Text

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

Iam using VS2015, Windows Forms Applications.
I wish to display my text by vertical direction. For that I found a class in c#. And hence I wish to convert the class from c# to c++/cli. Thanks.

myLabel-Class()

```
using System.Drawing;
class myLabel:System.Windows.Forms.Label
{
    public int RotateAngle { get; set; }  // to rotate your text
    public string NewText { get; set; }   // to draw text
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Brush b =new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);           
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(this.RotateAngle);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.NewText, this.Font,b , 0f, 0f);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

And I tried from myside to convert it to c++/cli as like the below, Does anyone can help me to correct it? Thanks.
MyLabel.h

```
#ifndef MyLabel_H
#define MyLabel_H

using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

public ref class MyLabel : Label
{
public:
    property int RotateAngle {
        int get() { return RotateAngle; }
        void set(int value) { RotateAngle = value; }
    }
    property String^ NewText {
        String^ get() { return NewText; }
        void set(String^ value) { NewText = value; }
    }
protected:
    virtual bool OnPaint(PaintEventArgs keydata) override;
};
#endif
```

And MyLabel.cpp

```
#include "MyLabel.h"

using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

bool MyLabel::OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ keydata) {
    Brush^ b = gcnew SolidBrush(this->ForeColor);
    keydata->Graphics->TranslateTransform(this->Width / 2, this->Height / 2);
    keydata->Graphics->RotateTransform(this->RotateAngle);
    keydata->Graphics->DrawString(this->NewText, this->Font, b, 0f, 0f);
    Label::OnPaint(keydata);
}
```

Note : from the above codes, Iam not clear with MyLabel.h get, set and MyLabel.cpp DrawString()
Thanks Again

Comment: In the declaration of `OnPaint` you have `PaintEventArgs keydata`. It should be: `PaintEventArgs^ keydata` (with `^` - like in the implementation).

Comment: The return type of OnPaint is `void`, not `bool` -- Your properties should be, e.g., `public: property float RotateAngle;  public: property System::String^ NewText;`  -- You should probably override the `Text` Property or use just that -- SolidBrush is disposable, so add `b->~Brush();` then `__super::OnPaint(e);` -- Change `keydata->DrawString(this->NewText, this->Font, b, .0f, .0f);`, same goes for the `TranslateTransform()` method -- As you can see, `RotateAngle` is now of Type `float`

Comment: As a note, `TranslateTransform()` should consider the size of the text, otherwise you most probably are drawing outside the Control's bounds

Answer (score 0):

MyLabel.h

```
#ifndef MyLabel_H
#define MyLabel_H

using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

public ref class MyLabel : Label
{
public: property float RotateAngle;  
public: property System::String^ NewText;
protected:
    virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ keydata) override;
};
#endif
```

MyLabel.cpp

```
#include "MyLabel.h"

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

void MyLabel::OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ keydata) {
    Brush^ b = gcnew SolidBrush(this->ForeColor);
    keydata->Graphics->TranslateTransform(this->Width / 2, this->Height / 2);
    keydata->Graphics->RotateTransform(this->RotateAngle);
    keydata->Graphics->DrawString(this->NewText, this->Font, b, .0F, .0F);
    Label::OnPaint(keydata);
}
```

Thanks To Jimi & Wohlstad..Your Comments helped me verymuch ! Thank Again !

Comment: You forgot to dispose of the Brush, you cannot forget about that. I suggest to change the code in `auto b = gcnew SolidBrush(this->ForeColor); //[...] b->~SolidBrush();` (since that's actually a SolidBrush) -- I also suggest using this form: `__super::OnPaint(keydata);` instead of `Label::OnPaint(keydata);`

Comment: Thank Jimi, updated & get cleared...Nice Jimi !